# Expo: Integrate 3rd party react-native lib that requires AppDelegate event listeners?

Tags: javascript, swift, react-native, expo

Trying to integrate [react-native-voip-push-notification](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-voip-push-notification) into an Expo app.

I created an Expo Module and wrote the event listeners using AppDelegate Subscribers.
However it must call into the 3rd party objc module that is not available to the Expo Module.

Does this mean you need to wrap/fork the library and/or paste the native objc module in your own Expo Module?

Or is there a way to just write the event listeners that call into an external native module?

this is what I got so far

```swift
import ExpoModulesCore
import PushKit 


public class MyVoipPushDelegate: ExpoAppDelegateSubscriber {

    public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        RNVoipPushNotificationManager.voipRegistration()
        return true
    }

    public func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
        RNVoipPushNotificationManager.didUpdatePushCredentials(credentials, forType: type.rawValue)
    }

    public func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didInvalidatePushTokenFor type: PKPushType) {
    }

    public func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) {
        let completion: (Bool) -> Void = { success in print(success ? "Voip success" : "Voip failed") }
        RNVoipPushNotificationManager.addCompletionHandler(payload.dictionaryPayload["uuid"], completionHandler: completion)
        RNVoipPushNotificationManager.didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload(payload, forType: type.rawValue)
    }
}
```

which gives me

```
^ cannot find 'RNVoipPushNotificationManager' in scope
```